# HTML line break in PHP string?

Tags: php, html

In Wordpress editor, following code is kind of different to me:

case #1

```
this is a test&nbsp;
```

case #2

```
this is a test
&nbsp;
```

The first case will add a space after the sentence, and the #2 case will leave an empty line under the sentence.

Now I am writing a PHP that will include html code in a PHP string,

```
$post_content = "...."
```

How to distinguish the two cases above in this $post_content variable?

If I write

```
$post_content += "this is a test";
$post_content += "&nbsp";
```

It's the fist case, how to write the #2 case?

Comment: Thanks, all. I marked the first reply as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newlines are represented by "\n":

`$post_content += "this is a test\n&nbsp;";`

Comment: I was using single quote and found out "\n" does not work in single quote. Just a note.

Answer (score 0):

```
$post_content += "this is a test\n";
$post_content += "&nbsp";
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is a newline. You denote it with `\n` In PHP you do it like this

```
$str = "This is a string.\nThis is the second line.";
```

In your case

```
$post_content = "this is a test\n&nbsp";
```